# Cannot insert the value NULL into column error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to run a migration. The migration goes through, however, when I try to update the database I get this error message

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'scheduleDateAndTimeid', table 'aspnet-ScheduleWebApp-20190525082521.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

I have two model classes, one called `student` and another called `scheduleDateAndTime`.

I created a DTO with mapping on the `student` model and added a navigation property to the `scheduleDateAndTime`

Migration

```
public partial class AnotherMigrationTwoTWOTwotwo : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Students", "scheduleDateAndTime_id", "dbo.ScheduleDateAndTimes");
        DropIndex("dbo.Students", new[] { "scheduleDateAndTime_id" });
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Students", name: "scheduleDateAndTime_id", newName: "scheduleDateAndTimeid");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Students", "scheduleDateAndTimeid", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.Students", "scheduleDateAndTimeid");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Students", "scheduleDateAndTimeid", "dbo.ScheduleDateAndTimes", "id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Students", "scheduleDateAndTimeid", "dbo.ScheduleDateAndTimes");
        DropIndex("dbo.Students", new[] { "scheduleDateAndTimeid" });
        AlterColumn("dbo.Students", "scheduleDateAndTimeid", c => c.Int());
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Students", name: "scheduleDateAndTimeid", newName: "scheduleDateAndTime_id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Students", "scheduleDateAndTime_id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Students", "scheduleDateAndTime_id", "dbo.ScheduleDateAndTimes", "id");
    }
}
```

`StudentDto` model class:

```
public class StudentDto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public byte age { get; set; }
    public string subjectStudying { get; set; }
    public string disability { get; set; }
    public string additionalInformation { get; set; }
    public ScheduleDateAndTimeDto ScheduleDateAndTime { get; set; }
    public int scheduleDateAndTimeid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Probably you have some null value in the column that you want to rename and set to nullable = false

Comment: That's one of the problems with migrations, it's hard to add new not-null columns. If `Student.ScheduleDateAndTime` is required you have to create `ScheduleDateAndTime` records before adding (or enabling) the FK constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You're trying to update a table by making a nullable foreign key a non-nullable foreign key**: if you're operating with an empty table (no records) this operation will just work fine, but if there are existing records the migration could encounter NULL values in those records for that column *(which was a valid value BEFORE the migration)*.

This could sound like a limit but makes absolutely sense: **if you’re updating the column to be not-nullable, how should a migration deal with existing data?** *(think about production environment releases, etc..)*

A work-around could be to first keep the column nullable, then update all the NULL values for the existing records and then make it not-nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `null` value in that column. Do some kind of update (for example `Sql("UPDATE t SET c = 1 WHERE c IS NULL")` for these `null` values before this migration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of botching your database to insert invalid data or breaking referential integrity, do the right thing and normalize your data:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentSchedule (
    studentID INT FOREIGN KEY Students.id,
    scheduleID INT FOREIGN KEY ScheduleDateAndTimes.id
)
```

Remove `Students.scheduleDateAndTime_id`. When you get a `Students.scheduleDateAndTime_id`, insert a row into `StudentSchedule`. If a student can have only one `scheduleDateAndTimeid` then make `StudentSchedule.studentID` unique.

Comment: But this doesn't (and can't) make the association required as a non-nullable FK can do. Also, normalization is about reducing redundancy by analyzing key-attribute dependencies. This added table doesn't improve any normalization level. From a normalization perspective it's even redundant, because all fields in 1:1-related tables could be in one table. So this is only a way to add a relationship to an existing model in a unobtrusive manner. It may be useful, but it's not better normalized.

Comment: It is normalized because the relation described is not 1:1. Read the question, he's trying to insert a null scheduleDateAndTimeid. The accepted answer suggests a null foreign key! Neither are 1:1, he needs an intersection table to maintain referential integrity.

Comment: `Student`-`StudentSchedule` is 1:1 if it is to represent 1:n between `Student` and `Schedule`. OP wants a required relationship and the accepted answer suggest a way to achieve that.